# vscode can't find typeRoots type definitions

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to have only one file to have most of the type definitions athat are going to be used in the whole application, i've created a folder called `@types`  and a `index.d.ts` file exporting every single interface/type i want.

Updated my tsconfig.json to include that folder:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./built",
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2015"
        ],
        "typeRoots": [
            "./@types"
        ],
    },
    "include": [
        "./client/**/*",
        "./@types/**/*"
    ],
    "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
        "silent": true,
        "errorsAsWarnings": true
    }
}
```

Even though, when in the code (inside client/...) i reference one of the interfaces present on index.d.ts, vscode throws a "Could not find name".

Is there a better way to fix this?

Interface definition present inside @types/index.d.ts.

```
export interface Agent {
    name: string;
...
}
```

Usage:

```
interface Props extends RouteComponentProps<any> {
    agent?: types.Agent;
}
```

Comment: Please add the code (both the declaration and the reference) to the question.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen definition + usage added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using the `export` keyword, `@types/index.d.ts` is treated as a module, and the only way to access types from it is to import them.  For example, after doing the following, you could refer to `types.Agent`:

```
import * as types from "../path/to/@types/index";
```

You may want to remove all occurrences of `export` so that `@types/index.d.ts` is treated as a global declaration file and you can refer to types simply as `Agent`.  Or you can put the types in a namespace called `types` and then refer to `types.Agent`.

The `typeRoots` compiler option is unrelated.  It tells the compiler where to find packages with declarations that should be loaded, but your problem is not loading the declarations (since `@types/index.d.ts` matches your `include`) but rather importing them.

Comment: Well, you got it. Now i was able to understand how declaration files work! Thanks.